# How to find whether a given path is absolute/relative and convert it to absolute for file manipulation?

Tags: regex, javascript

I am writing a small windows script in javascript/jscript for finding a match for a regexp with a string that i got by manipulating a file.

The file path can be provided relative or absolute. How to find whether a given path is absolute/relative and convert it to absolute for file manipulation?

Answer (score 6):

> How to find whether a given path is absolute/relative ...

From the MSDN article [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths):

> A file name is relative to the current directory if it does not begin with one of the following:
>
> - A UNC name of any format, which always start with two backslash characters ("\\"). For more information, see the next section.
> - A disk designator with a backslash, for example "C:\" or "d:\".
> - A single backslash, for example, "\directory" or "\file.txt". This is also referred to as an *absolute path*.

So, strictly speaking, an *absolute path* is the one that begins with a single backslash (`\`). You can check this condition as follows:

```
if (/^\\(?!\\)/.test(path)) {
  // path is absolute
}
else {
  // path isn't absolute
}
```

But often by an *absolute path* we actually mean a *fully qualified path*. In this is the case, you need to check all three conditions in order to distinguish between full and relative paths. For example, your code could look like this:

```
function pathIsAbsolute(path)
{
  if ( /^[A-Za-z]:\\/.test(path) ) return true;
  if ( path.indexOf("\\") == 0 )   return true;
  return false;
}
```

or (using a single regex and a bit less readable):

```
function pathIsAbsolute(path)
{
  return /^(?:[A-Za-z]:)?\\/.test(path);
}
```

---

> ... and convert it to absolute for file manipulation?

Use the [`FileSystemObject.GetAbsolutePathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx1xa64f.aspx) method:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var full_path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the path is relative or absolute, look for a leading `/`.
If it doesn't have one, you need to concatenate the path to a base path. Some programming environments have a "current working directory", but Javascript that lives in the browser doesn't, so you just need to pick a base path and stick to it.

```
function full_path(my_path) {
    var base_path = "/home/Sriram/htdocs/media";
    var path_regex = /^\/.*$/;
    if(path_regex.test(my_path)) {
        return my_path;
    } else {
        return base_path + my_path;
    }
}
```

Paths can contain newlines, which the javascript regex `.` won't match, so you might want to develop a more sophisticated regex to make sure all paths will work properly. However, I'd consider that outside the scope of this answer, and of my knowledge. :-)

Comment: Leading `/` isn't very relative - it points to the root. A relative path can be `images/smile.gif`, `../parent.txt`, etc.

Comment: Everything is normal: he said that path is relative if it doesn't start with a `/`, what is true.

Comment: didn't he say he's writing a script for windows?

Comment: how do you find whether a path provided is absolute or relative for windows? Is there any way I can achieve it through Windows Script Host's builtin functions?

Comment: this is my my logic: if it has a ':' in it then it gotta be a absolute path as ':' is placed after the root directory.

Comment: I somehow missed that this was a "windows script", as in, a javascript shell for a MS Windows system. I've never seen such a beast, and wouldn't have answered if I'd understood the question better. ^.^  

As I wrote above, I think my answer is accurate for javascript that lives in the browser.