# regex to check path is relative or absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I am tracking onclick event on "a" tag , onclick function will get the href attr of "a" tag . i want to check the href is absolute path or relative path. is there any regex expression to check it.

and other then this pattern

```
"/myfolder/test.txt"
"http://example.com"
"https://example.com"
```

which are the other pattern i have to check.

Comment: It might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406739/how-to-find-whether-a-given-path-is-absolute-relative-and-convert-it-to-absolute

Comment: Note that most answers here don't take into account protocol-less URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to test all of the anchor tags you can do this. The RegEx patter checks for any typos A.K.A. fat fingers.

```
function checkRelpath(){
    var anChrs = $('a');

    $.each(anChrs, function(idx, itm){
        var pattern = new RegExp('/^(http|https|http:|https:|\/\/)/'),
            path = $(itm).prop('href'),
            testPath = pattern.test(path);

        console.log(path);
        console.log(testPath);
    });
}
```

Or if you want to test a specific anchor you could do this.

```
function checkThisRelpath(a){
    var pattern = new RegExp('/^(http|https|http:|https:|\/\/)/'),
        path = $(a).prop('href'),
        testPath = pattern.test(path);

        console.log(path);
        console.log(testPath);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you bother with a regex? Use `str.startsWith`:

```js
console.log("/myfolder/test.txt".startsWith("/"));
console.log("http://example.com".startsWith("/"));
console.log("https://example.com".startsWith("/"));
```

---

If you need to consider the case of paths starting with `/` or `~`:

```js
console.log(/^([?/~]|mailto.*@.*\.\w+$)/.test("mailto:mail@example.org"));
console.log(/^([?/~]|mailto.*@.*\.\w+$)/.test("~/myfolder/test.txt"));
console.log(/^([?/~]|mailto.*@.*\.\w+$)/.test("/myfolder/test.txt"));
console.log(/^([?/~]|mailto.*@.*\.\w+$)/.test("http://example.com"));
console.log(/^([?/~]|mailto.*@.*\.\w+$)/.test("https://example.com"));
```

Comment: When I get the question correctly, it should cover all listed variants, startsWith would only cover the first.

Comment: seems to be my misreading. Title of this question indicates you're correct.  What I thought was that he wanted a solution to match '/' and 'http(s)://' - sorry.

Comment: What about query strings: **?hello=world** which it is not an absolute uri?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using [URI.js#is](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#is):

```js
function isAbsoluteUri(str) {
  var uri = new URI(str);
  return uri.is('absolute');
}

console.log(isAbsoluteUri('/myfolder/test.txt'));
console.log(isAbsoluteUri('~/myfolder/test.txt'));
console.log(isAbsoluteUri('?hello=world'));
console.log(isAbsoluteUri('http://example.com'));
console.log(isAbsoluteUri('https://example.com'));
console.log(isAbsoluteUri('ftp://example.com'));
console.log(isAbsoluteUri('mailto:mail@example.com'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.18.2/URI.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changed the function name for consistency: `isAbsoluteUri('http://example.com')` === `true` Thanks

Comment: Well played @YosvelQuintero. Good knowledge and usage of the language.

Answer (score 4):

If you know you're always getting a valid path, then all you really have to do is check if it starts with a `/`. This should do it:

```
^\/.*
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/rdox2A/1

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Return true is the URL is absolute
 * 
 * @export
 * @param {string} url 
 * @returns
 */
export function isURLAbsolute(url) {
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a string');
    }
    return /^[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*:/.test(url);
}
```

Comment: How is `foo:bar` an absolute URL?